# Strings are empty in ResultSet (Weblogic 12c + Oracle 9i)

Tags: java, jdbc, weblogic12c, oracle9i

I have an application working properly in WL 11 (JDK 1.6) + Oracle 9i. When I migrate to WL12 (JDK1.8), all the strings in the results are empty but the other fields are OK (int, date...)

In both server, I have a datasource with `oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource` driver.

¿Any idea? ¿Do I have to change driver at WL console?

```
Statement stm = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rst = stm.executeQuery(query);
```

Edit: I have deploy another app in Oracle 11g DB and works properly. Could not work properly with Oracle 9i?

Comment: Are the drivers the same version? If not try upgrading to the last. This may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17530909/java-returns-empty-string-value-for-oracle-varchar2

Comment: First of all, thanks for the answer. I have update OJDBC7.jar  and remove all the OJDBC6.jar/OJDBC14.jar from WL. Also i add to the classpath the reference to OJDBC7.jar, but nothing change.

Answer (score 0):

For someone who maybe comes for the answer, just get the resultset like this:

```
byte[] cod = rs.getBytes("COD");

codServ = new String(cod);
```